# How to provide dependency for using strategies in Strategy implementation

Tags: c#, strategy-pattern

I need to create a query api. So, I have created following code structure

```
   interface IDataProvider
    {
      IEnumerable<SomeData> GetData()
    }


    class FirstDataProvider : IDataProvider

    {
         private IojectRequiredForCalucation _instance
       public FirstDataProvider(IojectRequiredForCalucation instance )    

      {
        this._instance = instance;
       }

        IEnumerable<SomeData> GetData()
        {
               // calculate using _instance object
        }
    }

         class SecondDataProvider : IDataProvider

    {
         private Iobject2 _instance
       public FirstDataProvider(IObject2 instance )    

      {
        this._instance = instance;
       }

        IEnumerable<SomeData> GetData()
        {
               // calculate using _instance object
        }
    }



    Class QueryApi
    {
         IDataProvider _dataProvider;

       public QueryApi(IDataProvider dataProvider)
       {
        this._dataProvder = dataProvider
       }

      public IEunmerable<DataToClient> GetDataForItem(Item item)
       {
              var someDatae = _dataProvider.GetData()
               // do some processing and return back data to client.
       }
     }
```

Now, I am going to expose the query api to Client.

> Who should be delegated the task of creating data provider Client or
>   framework itself(QueryApi)??

In my case i am the client and creator. So, I can do anything whatever I want but I want to know in real use cases, what is best way to delegate the creation of provider and how to provide dependency of these providers.

Comment: You might be over-engineering this - I'm curious why you're implementing this pattern at all.

Comment: there may be different different approach for fetching data. So for every new approach we will have new data provider.Query api would remain  same only correct provider has to be hooked.

Comment: What is the dependency you are mentioned in the tittle?

Comment: for the provider classes IObject2 and IIojectRequiredForCalucation

Comment: You are looking for the Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control pattern

Comment: This question is much more tricky and ambiguous than you might realise. The _answer_ to your question is subjective, and opinions would be based on information not provided (such as your composition model or lack thereof, whichever the case may be). Given that you've stated that you have control of both service and consumer, the choice is yours.

Comment: @Smudge202 I also understand this. therefore I am going delete very soon if don't get any response (ha ha)